# Hide R code chunks from outline view in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

When writing .rmd or .Rnw reports in RStudio, the outline view shows both code chunks and regular sections. While code chunks appear italic, regular sections do not. However, writing large reports with many similar named chunks will lead to a really bulky outline view with many similar labels.

[image]

Is there currently a way to turn one of them off? Either regular sections or the code chunks.

Comment: Under global options -> Rmarkdown. Does changing the option in "Show in document outline" help? I have mine set to show sections only.

Comment: @PhilipParker → answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per my comment: `global options -> Rmarkdown -> show in document outline` change to `show sections only`

Comment: Under Global Options -> Code -> Display -> R Markdown I only have the following three options: `Show inline tool bar for R code chunks`, `Show document outline by default`, `Show unnamed entries in document outline`. However, no drop down option named `show in document outline`. RStudio Version 0.99.903 (newest)

Comment: I am running version 0.99.1184. The option is available in that version.

Comment: i.e. You need the preview version not the latest stable release.